# Que signifie « jamais » dans « ne... jamais que » ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, négation, adverbes, conjonctions

Que signifie l'adverbe *jamais* dans les exemples suivants :

> Tant de jours pour réunir les papiers, tant de jours pour publier les
>   bans à l'église : oui, cela ne mènerait **jamais** qu'au 20 ou 25 du mois
>   pour les noces. (Loti)
>
> Soldats Sud-Vietnamiens s'entraînant au maniement du fusil américain
>   M-16, qui n'a **jamais** que vingt-cing ans d'avance sur les flingots de
>   la seconde guerre mondiale. (A. Clément)

Comment: The meaning I have in mind for "jamais" in "ne ... jamais que" is: the limited quality of whatever is modified by the restrictive  "ne ... que" ***invariably holds true for good***: "***ever***", "***under all circumstances***". As mentioned in my answer, I perceive the "jamais"s in the following three instances to be more or less the same: "*Tout ce qui sort de sa bouche, ce ne sont **jamais** que des excuses pour se la couler douce*" and "*Voilà bien le meilleur café que j'aie **jamais** bu*" and "*Si **jamais** la couleur du chapeau que vous choisissez ne vous convient finalement pas*".

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Il se peut que _invariably holding true for good_ se rapproche de _somme toute_ ou _après tout_ mais ta réponse ne contient pas cette explication. Il n'est pas démontré que _ever_ ou _under all circumstances_ puissent être équivalents à _somme toute_ et _après tout_ ; en fait wiktionnaire donne plutôt _in sum/short/conclusion_ et _after all_ respectivement. Dans la première phrase que tu présentes _jamais_ signifie l'un ou l'autre ; dans la deuxième, _à un moment quelconque_ ; dans la troisième, probablement _au cas où_. Ce n'est pas plus ou moins équivalent à mon avis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La formule *ne... jamais que* est un exemple de cas où la valeur temporelle de *jamais* s'est atténuée ou perdue : il signifie « **[somme toute](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/somme_toute), [après tout](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/apr%C3%A8s_tout)** » (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, §1006 d 4°, où l'on trouvera aussi les exemples en question).